# Bootstrap: 1 column on left 1 on the middle without scaling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I have this code: https://www.bootply.com/a0wTkTuKyG

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:red">
      Sidebar<br>Sidebar<br>Sidebar<br>Sidebar<br>Sidebar<br>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:yellow">
      Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

As you can see there is a big remaining white area right to the yellow "Content" div. I want that when I scale (resize) the window horizontally first shrink the white area and only when it's over re-scale or break the red and blue divs.

I also want to add some margin between the sidebar and the content which should be reduced first as well.

So I want the same as "container" class behaves. Keep the content size until it is possible and only re-size content when windows size become small enough.

Can I do it with bootstrap?

Comment: what blue div? Do you mean yellow?

Comment: Nope, no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @Naomi Thanks, fixed

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know  you can get close with bootstrap, if i understood you well this might help you:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" style="background-color:red">
   Sidebar<br>Sidebar<br>Sidebar<br>Sidebar<br>Sidebar<br>
  </div>  
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-7 col-xs-8" style="background-color:yellow">
   Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>
  </div>  
 </div>  
</div>
```